# Kotlin Conflicting overloads: public open fun statements()

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an interface Persistable which looks like this, the   `<T extends Statement<T>> List<Statement<T>>` is to allow it to support both BoundedStatements and SimpleStatements in data stax 4.x driver.

```
public interface Persistable {

    <T extends Statement<T>> List<Statement<T>> statements();

}
```

This java interface is inherited by Kotlin class A such that

```
data class UpdateRule(
        private val something: S) : Persistable {

    override fun statements(): List<Statement<BoundStatement> {
        return PutKeyValue(Function(orgId, serviceId), JsonUtil.toJson(rule)).statements() //this returns BoundStatement
    }
}
```

However, this gives the error `Conflicting overloads`.This code seems to work in Java(although with a warning), but in Kotlin it does not allow at all, how can I resolve this while also making sure parent interface remains generic to both Bound and Simple Statement?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper , this is helpful, if you would like to submit this as an answer, will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what the generics in `Persistable` mean. As it is written right now, you are supposed to implement the `statements` method so that it can handle *any* kind of `T` that `extends Statement<T>`. The generics there doesn't mean "implement this by choosing a kind of statement that you like".

It only produces a warning in Java because Java's generics is broken. Because of type erasure, `List<Statement<BoundStatement>` and `List<Statement<T>>` both erase to the same type - `List`, so the method in `UpdateRule` does implement the method in the interface if you consider the erasures. OTOH, type erasure isn't a thing in Kotlin (at least not in Kotlin/Core).

To fix this, you can move the generic type parameter to the interface:

```java
public interface Persistable<T extends Statement<T>> {
    List<Statement<T>> statements();
}
```

```kotlin
data class UpdateRule(private val something: S) :     
    Persistable<BoundStatement> {

    override fun statements(): List<BoundStatement> =
        PutKeyValue(Function(orgId, serviceId), JsonUtil.toJson(rule)).statements()
}
```

Notice how when we are implementing the interface, we can now specify the specific `T` that we are implementing for.

Answer (score 1):

In Java just like in Kotin, the value of the type parameter of a generic method is determined by the *caller* of the method, and can be different at every call of the method, even on the same instance.

In your specific case, with the Java interface declared like this, `statements()` is supposed to be implemented in such a way that the caller can choose which type of statement will be returned by a given call to this method. This is not the case in your implementation, and that's why Kotlin doesn't allow it. As pointed out by @Sweeper, Java is broken in this respect and might let you get away with a warning.

This is different when using a generic *class* or *interface*. If you define the type parameter at the class/interface level, then the value of that type parameter is determined at construction time of the class, or can be fixed by subclasses. For a given instance, all calls to the method will return a well known type, which is (I believe) what you want here.

You can do this in Java:

```java
public interface Persistable<T extends Statement<T>> {

    List<Statement<T>> statements();
}
```

And then in Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class UpdateRule(
        private val something: S
) : Persistable<BoundStatement> {

    override fun statements(): List<BoundStatement> {
        return PutKeyValue(Function(orgId, serviceId), JsonUtil.toJson(rule)).statements() //this returns BoundStatement
    }
}
```